# how to get value of age field after its gets calculated from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have used a jquery to calculate the age from date picker now i want to pass the value to controller in angular js . I am able to pass all the form values except the dob and age field .can some tell me how to pass the value of age and date.I have tried but still i cant able to get the value of these two fields. I am attaching my codes and screenshots below

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS & JS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="demoController">


    <form >
        <legend>Angularjs Form</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Your Name" ng-model="user.name">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">DOB</label>
                <input type="text" name="" id="patientDob" class="form-control" value="dob" required="required" title="" ng-model="user.date">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Age</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patientAge"  ng-model="user.age" ng-init="user.age">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Gender</label><br><br>
            <label><input type="radio" value="male" ng-model="user.gender">Male</label>
            <label><input type="radio"  value="female" ng-model="user.gender">Female</label>

        </div>

        <label for="">Relationship</label>

        <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in relation">

            <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.relation" checklist-value="item"/>{{item}}
        </div>



        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit() | json">Submit</button>
    </form>

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function () 
{
 console.log($(document).width());           
     $('#patientDob').datepicker
    ({
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1900:2150',
        maxDate: new Date(),
        inline: true,

             onSelect: function() {
               var birthDay = document.getElementById("patientDob").value;
                var DOB = new Date(birthDay);
                var today = new Date();
                var age = today.getTime() - DOB.getTime();
                age = Math.floor(age / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));

                document.getElementById('patientAge').value = age;
            }
     });  

});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
/**
* demo Module
*
* Description
*/
var app = angular.module('demo', ["checklist-model"]);


app.controller('demoController',function($scope){

    $scope.relation=['father','mother','self','son','daughter','spouse'];
    $scope.formDetails = [];



     $scope.user = {
    relation: ['self']
  };

    $scope.submit= function(){
        $scope.data = $scope.user;
        console.log($scope.data)
        $scope.formDetails.push($scope.data);
        console.log($scope.formDetails)

    }

})
```

[image: Form screenshot]

[image: console screenshot]

Comment: Can you try with ng-change function then call a function with date value, and in angular function assign that value to the scope variable before submit.?

Comment: can you post a sample code ??